# Xamarin Form: Multiple TapGestureRecognizers not work on IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, uitapgesturerecognizer

```
<Image 
                    x:Name="btnThickness"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    Source="width"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"  
                    WidthRequest="40" 
                    HeightRequest="40">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TappedBehaviourEvent"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer BindingContext="{x:Reference widthPicker}" Command="{Binding OpenCommand}"></TapGestureRecognizer>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
```

I have written an xaml file which have an image with two tap gesture recogniser: First TapGesture is to set the other view's visible to false and the second tap gesture is to show a selected view. On Android, it works fine and able to  call the TappedBehaviourEvent and the second command whereas on IOS it only call the second line of the TapGesture not the first one.

Is there something need to be added to have it work...

Comment: I've attempted to reproduce this and I do see some similar behavior. I filed an issue for that here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45014. If you additional samples or context, please add a comment to that bug report.

Comment: I tried.. I am very new to these environment don't know if a bug or a limitation.

Comment: no problem. I filed the bug for investigation. You can add yourself to the CC list of the bug report to get notifications and updates on it's progress.

Comment: Same issue 14/10/2019